# Recursive function call with setTimeout limited to ~200 calls per second, why?

Tags: javascript

This code recursively calls the same function with a setTimeout of 1 millisecond, which in theory should call the function 1000 times per second. However, it's only called about 200 times per second:

This behavior happens on different machines and different browsers, I checked if it's has something to do with the maximum call stack, but this limit is actually way higher than 200 on any browser.

```js
const info = document.querySelector("#info");
let start = performance.now();
let iterations = 0;

function run() {  
  if (performance.now() - start > 1000) {
    info.innerText = `${iterations} function calls per second`;
    start = performance.now();
    iterations = 0;
  }
  
  iterations++;
  setTimeout(run, 1);
}

run();
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Comment: Please read [this](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#zero-delay-settimeout). The answer here is misleading you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a limitation of how often nested timers can run. The HTML5 standard says: 11: "If nesting level is greater than 5, and timeout is less than 4, then set timeout to 4."

This is true only for client-side engines (browsers). In Node.JS this limitation does not exist

[HTML Standard Timers Section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timers)
[Very similar example from javascript.info](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#zero-delay-settimeout)

Comment: The OP isn't talking about nested timers. The OP is talking about a recursive timer.

Comment: I am sorry but this is the right answer. Check out [this](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#zero-delay-settimeout) example from javascript.info it's exactly the same as the question.

Comment: Seems this is the correct answer. "If nesting level is greater than 5, and timeout is less than 4, then set timeout to 4." It also makes sense that different machines/browsers give me the same result of 200 calls per second.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Recursive  = nested in this case

Answer (score 1):

The delay argument passed to `setTimeout` and `setInterval` is not a guaranteed amount of time. It's the **minimum** amount of time you could expect to wait before the callback function is executed. It doesn't matter how much of a delay you've asked for, if the JavaScript call stack is busy, then anything in the event queue will have to wait.

Also, there is an absolute minimum amount of time you could reasonably expect a callback to be called after which is dependent on the internals of the client.

From the [HTML5 Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timers):

> This API does not guarantee that timers will run exactly on schedule.
> Delays due to CPU load, other tasks, etc, are to be expected.

I once read somewhere that it was around 16ms so setting a delay of anything less than that shouldn't really change the timings at all.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The limitation isn't about resources but built-in the Javascript engines to be 4ms after 5 calls.

Comment: @AmitHadary No, it's not. The same link that you shared includes the quote that I've posted here in my answer.

Comment: @MiskoJones Why? Both use the same underlying JS engine and all browsers operate similarly when it comes to the call stack and the event queue.

Comment: Actually @AmitHadary answer makes sense with further testing showing me 4-5ms delay between function calls and would explain why it's matched between different browsers and different machines. Do you have any resource on that?

Comment: @MiskoJones I've included the resource in my answer... the HTML Spec.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Chrome and Firefox don't use the same underlying JS engine. Chrome uses V8 while Firefox uses Spidermonkey.